# How do I store the x or y value of a named node in tikz \draw?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, calculations, coordinates

A big part of the question above has already been answered: ["Use the `calc` `tikzlibrary` and the `let` syntax"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18393/791).

> ```
> \begin{tikzpicture}
>   \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (4,4);
>   \node (A) at (2,1) {A};
>   \path let \p1 = (A) in node  at (\x1,3) {B};
> \end{tikzpicture}
> ```

But it leaves out something else. How do I use the `let` syntax inside a `\draw` directive? Like so:

```
\draw
  (5,0) node(A){}
  let \p1 = A     % This line borks everything. What is the right thing to do?
  (0,5) -- (\x1,5)
  ;
```

Comment: Not sure, but I think next questions can help you http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18389/tikz-node-at-same-x-coordinate-as-another-node-but-specified-y-coordinate/18418#18418 or [tikz-how-to-connect-nodes-and-specify-line-direction](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22816/tikz-how-to-connect-nodes-and-specify-line-direction/22954#22954)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping this solution does understand your objective. It seems that given node A you wish to draw a line from (0,5) to (\x1,5), where \x1 is the coordinate of A. And you want this be done in one `draw` directive. That is from A to B in this demonstration.

The `let` command saves coordinate of A and one can use (\x1,\y1) later.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  (5,0) node (A){A} let \p1 =(A) in node at (\x1,5){}  (5,0) --(\x1,5) node(B){B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Update: just realize the OP wants line CB, so a minor revision is given here.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  (5,0) node (A) {} let \p1 =(A) in node at (\x1,5){} (0,5) node(C){C} --(\x1,5) node(B) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
```