# Strange error with tikz arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am trying to get tikz to draw some arrows for me and I keep getting the following error message:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/line' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \path [line] (
```

When I try using a test document, everything works well but it does not work in my intended document.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 5cm, auto]
    \node [startstop] (ba) {Block A};
    \node [startstop, right of=ba] (bb) {Block B};
    \path [line] (ba) -- (bb);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is the rough structure of my document:

```
%Some other packages used here
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}


\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm,
    minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
%% Edit Begin %%
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
%% Edit End %%

%% Some matter here

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 5cm, auto]
    \node [startstop] (ba) {Block A};
    \node [startstop, right of=ba] (bb) {Block B};
    %% Works
    %% \path [line] (ba) -- (bb);
    %% Does not work
    \draw [arrow] (ba) -- (bb);
\end{tikzpicture}

%% More matter
\end{document}
```

Is there something silly that I am missing here?

When I compile the document, I do see the blocks but not the arrows and I have looked into almost all the posts about similar issues on the internet and the issue is typically not using the right `\usetikzlibrary` commands.

In my case, I am using all the right libraries but I still keep getting this cryptic error message.

Please help.

--- Edit ---

Added the tikzstyle definition for "line".

When I try to use the inbuilt `arrow`, I get a similar error message:

`Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/arrow' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \draw [arrow]`

For now, I can proceed using the "line" that I am defining but would be nice to know why the `\draw [arrow]` does not work.

Comment: You don't have any `style` called `line`. At least it's not present in the code you showed to us.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `[arrow]` isn't a predefined style either, which is why you're getting the exact same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error occurs because there is no default `line` style for TikZ, even in the libraries you're using. Thus, if you want to use it in your code, you must define it with `\tikzstyle`. If you adapted your code from a question such as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22816/tikz-how-to-connect-nodes-and-specify-line-direction), then you should add to your preamble something like `\tikzstyle{line}=[draw]`, which will allow you to use `line` in your code as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\tikzstyle{line}=[draw] % here
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm,
    minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 5cm, auto]
    \node [startstop] (ba) {Block A};
    \node [startstop, right of=ba] (bb) {Block B};
    \path [line] (ba) -- (bb);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This will draw a line between the two nodes. If you prefer a different style, you can change the `\tikzstyle` definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback! I have updated the question. After defining the tikzstyle, I am able to draw the arrows as required but I still get an error message while using `\draw [arrow]`.
Would like to know whats up with that one...I have used tikz in the past also but never faced this kind of an issue...

Comment: Have you added `\tikzstyle{arrow}=[draw, -latex]` to your preamble?

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem.

Using: `\draw [->] (ba) -- (bb);` rather than `\draw [arrow] (ba) -- (bb);` fixed it for me.

I am only a beginner in LaTeX so sorry if this is not applicable to you!. I am using MacOS X 10.9.5 and compiling on TeXshop via the built in button.