# Different approach?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, node-connections

I'm trying on my first tikz diagram, and it's working okay, but I've run into some problems and I think that my solution is starting to be more discretionary. 
Heres my code:

```
\documentclass[png,border=10pt,tikz]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,fit,shapes,calc}
\tikzset{
    state/.style={
           rectangle,
           rounded corners,
           draw=black, very thick,
           minimum height=2em,
           inner sep=2pt,
           text centered,
           },
}

\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex]

\pgfdeclarelayer{bg}    % declare background layer
\pgfsetlayers{bg,main}

\begin{document}


\tikzset{
    block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, rounded corners, 
            minimum height=2em, minimum width=10em},
    block2/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, rounded corners, 
            minimum height=2em, minimum width=10em},  
    block3/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
            minimum height=4em, minimum width=30em},             
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2.5cm, >=latex]

\node[block3] (kronos) {Kronos};
\node[block, above of= kronos, anchor=north east] (interbank) {Interbank};
\node[block, above of= kronos, anchor=north west] (pengepolitik) {Pengepolitiske operationer};

\node[block, below = of kronos, anchor=south] (sum) {Sum-, intraday- og Straksclearing};
\node[block, left of = sum] (scp) {SCP};
\node[block, left = of scp] (vp) {VP};

\node[block, right of = sum] (euro) {EuroCCP};
\node[block, right of = euro] (cls) {CLS}; 

\node[block, below of= vp] (valuta) {Valutahandler};
\node[block, below of= scp] (detail) {Detailhandler};
\node[block, below of= cls] (værdi) {Værdipapirhandler};

\draw[dotted,thick] ($(interbank.north west)+(-0.3,0.3)$) rectangle ($(pengepolitik.south east)+(0.3,-0.3)$);

\draw[dotted,thick] ($(vp.north west)+(-0.3,0.3)$) rectangle ($(cls.south east)+(0.3,-0.3)$);



\path[line] (pengepolitik) -- (kronos);
\path[line] (interbank) -- (kronos);
\path[line] (scp) -- (kronos);
\path[line] (euro) -- (kronos);
\path[line] (vp) -- (kronos);
\path[line] (cls) -- (kronos);

\begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}    % select the background layer
       \draw[dashed] ($(kronos.west)+(-6,0)$) -- ($(kronos.east)+(6,0)$);
    \end{pgfonlayer}


\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Some of my problems are pretty obvious:

[image]

But I'm trying to achieve something like this:
[image]

Therefor i'm also looking for a way to do the straigth lines instead of lines going to the center of the main figure?
Do you have a better solution that I could try to do?

Regards,
Frederik.

Comment: Does it help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22954/1952

Answer (score 1):

You're more or less already there. Beneath some smaller syntax errors, you made bad use of the anchors of your nodes.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,fit,shapes,calc}
\tikzset{
    state/.style={
           rectangle,
           rounded corners,
           draw=black, very thick,
           minimum height=2em,
           inner sep=2pt,
           text centered,
           },
}

\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex]

\pgfdeclarelayer{bg}    % declare background layer
\pgfsetlayers{bg,main}

\begin{document}


\tikzset{
    block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, rounded corners, 
            minimum height=2em, minimum width=10em},
    block2/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, rounded corners, 
            minimum height=2em, minimum width=10em},  
    block3/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
            minimum height=4em, minimum width=30em},             
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2.5cm, >=latex]

\node[block3] (kronos) {Kronos};
\node[block, above left = 3em of kronos, anchor=south west] (interbank) {Interbank};
\node[block, above right = 3em of kronos, anchor=south east] (pengepolitik) {Pengepolitiske operationer};

\node[block, below = 3em of kronos] (sum) {Sum-, intraday- og Straksclearing};
\node[block, left = 3em of sum] (scp) {SCP};
\node[block, left = 3em of scp] (vp) {VP};

\node[block, right = 3em of sum] (euro) {EuroCCP};
\node[block, right = 3em of euro] (cls) {CLS}; 

\node[block, below = 3em of vp] (valuta) {Valutahandler};
\node[block, below = 3em of scp] (detail) {Detailhandler};
\node[block, below = 3em of cls] (værdi) {Værdipapirhandler};

\draw[dotted,thick] ($(interbank.north west)+(-0.3,0.3)$) rectangle ($(pengepolitik.south east)+(0.3,-0.3)$);

\draw[dotted,thick] ($(vp.north west)+(-0.3,0.3)$) rectangle ($(cls.south east)+(0.3,-0.3)$);

\path[line] (pengepolitik) -- (kronos);
\path[line] (interbank) -- (kronos);
\path[line] (scp) -- (kronos);
\path[line] (euro) -- (kronos);
\path[line] (vp) -- (kronos);
\path[line] (cls) -- (kronos);

\begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}    % select the background layer
       \draw[dashed] ($(kronos.west)+(-6,0)$) -- ($(kronos.east)+(6,0)$);
    \end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]