# Matrices and TikZ : arrows inside the matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the example below, the arrows fit inside the matrix but I would like them to stop at the limit of the delimiters.

```
    \documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing, calc, positioning,fit}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick,baseline]
    \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)](A){ 
    a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \dots  & a_{1,j} & \dots & a_{1,n}\\
    a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \dots  & a_{2,j} & \dots & a_{2,n}\\  
    \vdots  & \vdots  &  & \vdots  &  & \vdots\\
    a_{i,1} & a_{i,2} & \dots  & a_{i,j} & \dots & a_{i,n}\\
    \vdots  & \vdots  &  & \vdots  &  & \vdots\\
    a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \dots  & a_{n,j} & \dots & a_{n,n}\\
   };

   \node[
     fit=(A-4-6)(A-4-6),
     inner xsep=20pt,inner ysep=0,
     label=right: $i$-ième ligne
    ](L) {};

   \node[
     fit=(A-6-4)(A-6-4),
     inner xsep=20pt,inner ysep=20pt,
     label=below: $j$-ième colonne
     ](C) {};

    \draw[->](L.east)-- (A-4-6);
    \draw[->](C.south)-- (A-6-4);

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an `xshift`:

```
 \documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing, calc, positioning,fit}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick,baseline]
    \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)](A){ 
    a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \dots  & a_{1,j} & \dots & a_{1,n}\\
    a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \dots  & a_{2,j} & \dots & a_{2,n}\\  
    \vdots  & \vdots  &  & \vdots  &  & \vdots\\
    a_{i,1} & a_{i,2} & \dots  & a_{i,j} & \dots & a_{i,n}\\
    \vdots  & \vdots  &  & \vdots  &  & \vdots\\
    a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \dots  & a_{n,j} & \dots & a_{n,n}\\
   };

   \node[
     fit=(A-4-6)(A-4-6),
     inner xsep=20pt,inner ysep=0,
     label=right: $i$-ième ligne
    ](L) {};

   \node[
     fit=(A-6-4)(A-6-4),
     inner xsep=20pt,inner ysep=20pt,
     label=below: $j$-ième colonne
     ](C) {};

    \draw[->](L.east)-- ([xshift=12pt]A-4-6.east);
    \draw[->](C.south)-- (A-6-4);

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Or shorten the arrow:

```
 \documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing, calc, positioning,fit}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick,baseline]
    \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)](A){ 
    a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \dots  & a_{1,j} & \dots & a_{1,n}\\
    a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \dots  & a_{2,j} & \dots & a_{2,n}\\  
    \vdots  & \vdots  &  & \vdots  &  & \vdots\\
    a_{i,1} & a_{i,2} & \dots  & a_{i,j} & \dots & a_{i,n}\\
    \vdots  & \vdots  &  & \vdots  &  & \vdots\\
    a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \dots  & a_{n,j} & \dots & a_{n,n}\\
   };

   \node[
     fit=(A-4-6)(A-4-6),
     inner xsep=20pt,inner ysep=0,
     label=right: $i$-ième ligne
    ](L) {};

   \node[
     fit=(A-6-4)(A-6-4),
     inner xsep=20pt,inner ysep=20pt,
     label=below: $j$-ième colonne
     ](C) {};

    \draw[->, shorten > =12pt](L.east)-- (A-4-6.east);
    \draw[->](C.south)-- (A-6-4);

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

And by the way why do you need `fit`?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick,baseline]
    \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)](A){ 
    a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \dots  & a_{1,j} & \dots & a_{1,n}\\
    a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \dots  & a_{2,j} & \dots & a_{2,n}\\  
    \vdots  & \vdots  &  & \vdots  &  & \vdots\\
    a_{i,1} & a_{i,2} & \dots  & a_{i,j} & \dots & a_{i,n}\\
    \vdots  & \vdots  &  & \vdots  &  & \vdots\\
    a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \dots  & a_{n,j} & \dots & a_{n,n}\\
   };

   \node[right =30pt of A-4-6.east](L)  {$i$-ième ligne};

   \node[below=20pt of A-6-4.south](C) {$j$-ième colonne};

    \draw[->, shorten > =12pt](L.west)-- (A-4-6.east);
    \draw[->](C.north)-- (A-6-4.south);

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Fabrice However, Ignasi's answer is more elegant.

Answer (score 6):

Matrix delimiters are `nodes` but unnamed by default. Therefore, if you add a name you can use them as reference like any other node and lines will stop on their borders.

In following code, I've used `every right delimiter` style to add a name which is used later on.

A matrix is an special kind of node which contains other nodes. So if you want to stop a line on `matrix` border you can use the matrix name as reference. Matrix elements have their own border. I've used intersection points between column center and south matrix border to place the vertical arrow and row center and east anchor on right delimiter to place the horizontal arrow. If you need to understand `-|` (or `|-`) syntax, look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481234/1952 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22954/1952.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing, calc, positioning,fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick,baseline,
every right delimiter/.append style={name=rd},
]
\matrix [matrix of math nodes, 
    left delimiter=(, 
    right delimiter=),
    ](A){ 
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \dots  & a_{1,j} & \dots & a_{1,n}\\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \dots  & a_{2,j} & \dots & a_{2,n}\\  
\vdots  & \vdots  &  & \vdots  &  & \vdots\\
a_{i,1} & a_{i,2} & \dots  & a_{i,j} & \dots & a_{i,n}\\
\vdots  & \vdots  &  & \vdots  &  & \vdots\\
a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \dots  & a_{n,j} & \dots & a_{n,n}\\
};

\draw[<-] (rd.east|-A-4-1.center)--++(0:6mm) node[right]{$i$-ième colonne};
\draw[<-] (A.south-|A-1-4.center) --++(-90:6mm) node[below]{$j$-ième colonne};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! It didn't come to my mind to name the node of the right delimeter, +1!

Comment: But the horizontal arrow should be aligned with the ith row...

Comment: @CarLaTeX you're right. I'll change as soon as I've a computer and Internet access at hand ;-)

Comment: Thank you, because your answer is really elegant!

Comment: @ Ignasi Could you explain this `(A.south-|A-1-4.center)` ? Thank you.

Comment: @Fabrice Look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481195/difference-between-and-in-tikz/481234#481234

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thank you.

Comment: @Ignasi Thank you for all the explanations, I progress with TikZ thanks to people like you.